# Should custom Magento code always be a module, regardless of size

Tags: class, best-practice

As a Magento newbie, I'm still trying to learn the good and the bad when it comes to developing for Magento.

I need to write a class, that in Yii I would just create a class in the 'vendors' directory and hey-presto.

Is there a similar place to put code in Magento or should I be creating a full module just for 1 class that initially will have 1 static function?

Answer (score 2):

I would always create a module when ever I need a class or simple rewrite. Even if it appears overhead it gives you greater control with dependencies. What I sometimes do is create one core module that I can put any code that really does not fit with anything.

Technically I think you can just put a local/Magento/YourModule and then the `getModel`/`helper` will fall back to it but for maintainability I would go for modules. In 3 months you will have forgotten what everything does and modules help to sort things.

Answer (score 2):

You can always add your class in the `lib` folder. It is also taken into consideration by the autoloader.
But I assume you are going to use that class somewhere in the code, otherwise what's the point?

I would go with the module approach. Is cleaner.